# Is Friedman's test for dependent samples or not?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, friedman-test

Which test should I use for hypothesis testing on more than two dependent non-parametric data?

The Friedman's test seems to be the option, as I have read in several books and webs, but, when I look for it on MatLab, [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/friedman.html), it says:

> Friedman's test makes the following assumptions about the data in X:
>
> All data come from populations having the same continuous distribution, apart from possibly different locations due to column and row effects.
>
> All observations are mutually independent.

Should I trust MatLab information? or is it that "observations being mutually independent" is different to independent samples? What does that mean then?

Should I then use Friedman's test with my dependent data? I am really confused.

Comment: Conditional on the blocking factor, they're independent. If you don't condition on it, they're dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your dependent variable is continuous and your independent variables are categorical. Otherwise, you can't use Friedman's test.

There is nothing wrong in Matlab's description, `mutually independent` just means each pair of your observations are independent.

If your experiment is repeated (or paired), and you're interested in testing for the treatment effects, then you can use it.